# Lighting in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I am drawing an elliposid with the following simple code

```
import graph3;

unitsize(1cm); 

import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(1,3.5,0.6,zoom=.8);
pen p=white+opacity(1);
real a=1.5,b=3,c=4.5; //Ellipsoid dimensions

// Draw Ellipsoid
draw(scale(a,b,c)*unitsphere,p);
```

The result is as follows; the dark side to the left is almost completely black. How can I make it brighter?

[image]

Comment: Without lights, for real 3D objects, some sides of the object will be dark. To overcome, one way is using opacity; however, we can put several light sources at different positions https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644709/140722